# android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: android, xml

I'm getting exception when i do following:

```
findViewById(R.id.some_container).setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50));
```

But when I change to `new LinearLayout.LayoutParams` that's ok. If `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` is child of `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` that why I can't cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `LinearLayout` is also a `ViewGroup` but not all `ViewGroup` is a `LinearLayout`. That's why you can't cast a `ViewGroup` to a `LinearLayout`

You can create a `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` from a `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` as follows:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = 
    new LayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50));
```

However, a simple cast is impossible.